# How to return a result from datalist without getting "undefined" error

Tags: javascript, html, html-datalist

When an option is selected from the `datalist`, I want that selected option to appear in the page and to do so simply by hitting the enter key. I'm a beginner coder. Perhaps the problem is `value` is undefined. How should I define it?

EDIT: I'm able to get the desired result if I specify the value, such as `[5]` however I'm not sure how to switch out `[5]` with a variable, let's say `[i]`.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        document.getElementById("myButton").click();
    }
});

function testResults(input) {
    var x = document.getElementById("myInput").options[5].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = x;
    }
```

```html
<input list="myInput" value="">
<button id="myButton" onClick="testResults(this.input)">submit</button>

<datalist id="myInput">
<option>Alabama</option>
<option>California</option>
<option>Hawaii</option>
<option>Indiana</option>
<option>Montana</option>
<option>Nevada</option>
<option>Vermont</option>
<option>Washington</option>
</datalist>

<p></p>
<div id="test">Selected option innerHTML goes here on keyCode === 13</div>
```

Comment: myInput is not defined anywhere in your code. Also if you use datalist, those values are just suggestions, you can actually write anything not there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made one change currently and rest logic of yours is still not clear to me.

Added `id="myInputId"`.

removed `input` variable from method `testResults()`

```js
var input = document.getElementById("myInputId");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        document.getElementById("myButton").click();
    }
});

function testResults() {
     /*var i = myInputId.options.indexOf(value);
    var x = document.getElementById("myInput").options[i].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = x;*/
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = input.value;
}
```

```html
<input list="myInput" id="myInputId" value="">
<button id="myButton" onClick="testResults()">submit</button>

<datalist id="myInput">
<option>Alabama</option>
<option>California</option>
<option>Hawaii</option>
<option>Indiana</option>
<option>Montana</option>
<option>Nevada</option>
<option>Vermont</option>
<option>Washington</option>
</datalist>

<p></p>
<div id="test">Selected option innerHTML goes here on keyCode === 13</div>
```

Comment: Here's what I want to do: whatever is submitted in the datalist input, I want that value to appear on the page in the innerHTML of the div where I noted "Selected option innerHTML goes here on keyCode ===13"

Comment: I edited my example to hopefully make it more clear what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I have updated my answer see if this is what you need

Comment: This is a great answer, I'm looking at it now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's clear to me now that I needed "id=" and that the "input list =" and "datalist id=" was not sufficient. Thanks again.